# Approximation of continuous polynomials by trigonometric polynomials in proof of Fejér Sum Convergence

Tags: fourier-analysis, fourier-series, harmonic-analysis

I'm trying to read through Terence Tao's notes on harmonic analysis and have gotten stuck on one of the basic examples he has provided on the utility of harmonic analysis.

The example aims to use a quantitative estimate on the $L^\infty$ norm of the Fejér sums of a continuous function $f$ to derive the qualitative property of uniform convergence of these sums to $f$.

In particular:

Given a $2\pi$-periodic, continuous function $f$ we have the estimate $||F_nf||_\infty \leq ||f||_\infty$. Where $F_nf$ is the nth Fejér sum of $f$. For trigonometric polynomials, we'll have uniform convergence of these Fejér sums. Additionally, we are able to approximate any continuous function on $[-\pi, \pi]$ via a trigonometric polynomial to any desired accuracy. It follows by the triangle inequality and linearity of the Fejér sums that $F_nf$ converges to $f$ uniformly.

What I can't seem to understand about this proof is the assertion that any continuous function on the interval $[-\pi, \pi]$ can be approximated to any desired accuracy by a trigonometric polynomial. Dr. Tao says this is a result of the Weierstrass Approximation theorem, but I can't see how to extend a statement about approximation by general polynomials to one about trigonometric polynomials. All sources I have found so far use the Fejér sum itself as the approximating polynomial, but that's using the result we're trying to establish. One author hints to being able to use the Weierstrass Approximation theorem directly, stating that we can pass from the interval to the circle, but he doesn't go into any details.

Any help here would be appreciated. 
Thanks in advance!

Comment: I guess more accurately we're using the Stone-Weierstrass theorem on density of self-adjoint algebras that separate points.

Comment: Ahh okay, I see Wikipedia has an explanation of this generalization

Comment: Suppose $f$ is continuous and periodic on $[-\pi,\pi]$. Then it is relatively easy to show that the Fejer means for $f$ converge uniformly to $f$. That gives uniform convergence of a sequence of trigonometric polynomials to $f$. Because the trigonometric polynomials can be uniformly approximated by polynomials using the power series for the trigonometric functions, you can obtain the uniform approximation of a continuous function by polynomials, which gives the Weierstrass approximation theorem, after a little adjustment at the endpoints of the interval to allow for non-periodicity.

Comment: The above is the standard approach.